# Keyboard is not hiding on ActionBar Tab change

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have implemented ActionBar Tab in my app. But I am facing one issue during tab change. My tabs contains mainly webview, but one tab contains edit text. **when i click on edit text keyboard appears, and with keyboard appearing if I am changing the tab, keyboard is not disappearing**. I tried few of the simple solution like hiding it explicitly, but no success.

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(fragment.getView().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
```

this i am calling in onTabSelected() of class that implements ActionBar.TabListener. I don't know how to solve this problem , neither getting relevant information.

Thanks in advance. Any help will appreciated.

***Update and Answer***

Eric answer somewhat gave me a push and helped me achieve the answer, so i am marking his answer as correct with my change. ie I have added the eric's code in my `onTabUnselected` but not in tabSelected, as when i was trying to get view at that moment view was not created thus was getting view as null. so my final code was

```
@Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        View target = initialisedFragment.getView().findFocus();

        if (target != null) 
        {
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(target.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can just pick a `View` and use it as the window token. You have to find the field that is currently showing the keyboard.

This is a port of a method I've used before, it's worth a try:

```
View target = fragment.getView().findFocus();
if (target != null) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) target.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(target.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

If that doesn't work, there's [lots of other methods that have been reported to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard).

Comment: ohh, k. I was not getting a view, because usually we pass tabHost to this view, but in action bar there was no tab host . So i preferred to pass this view. thanks for the reply. I am trying this out. Thanks again.

Comment: this is not working and even your link is passing a editText as view. but here i don't have any view as such because fragment.getView() is always passed as null. even adding alwaysHidden in manifest is also not working. Don't know how to proceed....

Comment: You need to figure out whatever has the focus. Perhaps using `getActivity()` or `getRootView()` of a view you do have, then finding the focus of that? If `getView()` is null then your `Fragment` probably either isn't laid out or isn't instantiated properly...

Comment: Thanks I found out my mistake and updated my question with my solution and since u helped me out in achieving this I marked your answer as correct instead of creating one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following, this option to capture the current view in which the device is working :

```
public final void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        View focus = getCurrentFocus();
        if (focus != null) {
            hiddenKeyboard(focus);
        }
    }
public final void onTabselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        View focus = getCurrentFocus();
        if (focus != null) {
            hiddenKeyboard(focus);
        }
    }
public final void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        View focus = getCurrentFocus();
        if (focus != null) {
            hiddenKeyboard(focus);
        }
    }
```